# Width on picture and vertical align

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

I need to make the picture to have a width on 100%, which means that the picture should fill out the white space, and align vertical with the text there is below.

[My Example Site](http://roulettesuite.com/new.html)

The code is for email newsletters, therefore I am using foundation. I cannot find how I am doing that in the documentation, therefore I have to try something else.

How can I make the picture fill out the whitespace?

**Relevant HTML code**

```
<body>
  <!-- Wrapper for the body of the email -->
  <table class="body" data-made-with-foundation>
    <tr>
      <!-- The class, align, and <center> tag center the container -->
      <td class="float-center" align="center" valign="top">
        <center>

          <table class="wrapper" align="center">
            <tr>
              <td class="wrapper-inner" style="background-color: blue;">
                <table align="center" class="container">
                  <tbody>
                    <tr>
                      <td>
                        <table class="row">
                          <tbody>
                            <tr>
                              <th class="small-12 large-12 columns first last">
                                <table>
                                  <tr>
                                    <th>
                                      <center data-parsed="">
                                        <img src="http://www.webdesignmo.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2010/02/6_lion.jpg" alt="image of clever meme that made me chuckle" align="center" class="float-center" width="100%">
                                      </center>
                                    </th>
                                    <th class="expander"></th>
                                  </tr>
                                </table>
                              </th>
                            </tr>
                          </tbody>
                        </table>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
          <table class="wrapper" align="center">
            <tr>
              <td class="wrapper-inner" style="background-color: red;">
                <table align="center" class="container" >
                  <tbody>
                    <tr>
                      <td>
                        <table class="row">
                          <tbody>
                            <tr>
                              <th class="small-12 large-12 columns first last" style="background-color: yellow;">
                                <table>
                                  <tr>
                                    <th>Here is all my text is gonna be. Here is all my text is gonna be.Here is all my text is gonna be.Here is all my text is gonna be.</th>
                                    <th class="expander"></th>
                                  </tr>
                                </table>
                              </th>
                            </tr>
                          </tbody>
                        </table>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
          <table class="wrapper" align="center">
            <tr>
              <td class="wrapper-inner" style="background-color: pink;">
                <table align="center" class="container" >
                  <tbody>
                    <tr>
                      <td>
                        <table class="row">
                          <tbody>
                            <tr>
                              <th class="small-12 large-12 columns first last" style="background-color: green;">
                                <table>
                                  <tr>
                                    <th>Here is all my text is gonna be.</th>
                                    <th class="expander"></th>
                                  </tr>
                                </table>
                              </th>
                            </tr>
                          </tbody>
                        </table>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>


    </center>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
```

Comment: <img style="width:100%;" src="foo.jpg"> ?

Comment: like this? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qRpJLR

Comment: The image has to be at least 600px wide. If it is not, you have to make it stretch with css. Bootstrap dos not render past the image size when you mark it 100% without adding the class `img-responsive`

Comment: curse you @Coker! Ha ha ha yeah what he wrote for you.

Comment: Thank you for the answers. It is not bootstrap but foundation, but probably the same thing :) @Coker: Did you only add `img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}` ?

Comment: @scoopzilla OP is using Foundation and not Bootstrap. Either way both frameworks use `max-width: 100%;` for their responsive images which does not allow the image to expand beyond the images natural size. Basically, adding the responsive class won't work.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Yes I can see that it is not working on Outlook: https://postimg.org/image/xyvq199ml/

Comment: @hungerstar Ah Yes I understand.

Comment: @McDuck4 yes, that's what Michael Coker did. He over-rode the default styling of `img` defined by Foundation for the `width` and `display` properties. It looks like Foundation already uses `display: block;` so you could drop that and only use `width: 100%;` in your CSS.

Comment: @McDuck4 very few html email things will work on Outlook. *shakes fist* **CURSE YOU OUTLOOK**

Comment: Hehe so true ;-) The answer @Jacinto Tárraga Hernández came up with almost solved the problem

Answer (score 1):

Well, you have to modify two things.

First of all:
Original code:

```
<table class="row">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th class="small-12 large-12 columns first last">
```

Final code:

```
<table class="row">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th class="small-12 large-12 columns first last" style="padding:0;">
```

And second: Original code:

```
<center data-parsed="">
    <img src="http://www.webdesignmo.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2010/02/6_lion.jpg" alt="image of clever meme that made me chuckle" align="center" class="float-center" width="100%">
</center>
```

Final code:

```
<center data-parsed="">
    <img src="http://www.webdesignmo.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2010/02/6_lion.jpg" alt="image of clever meme that made me chuckle" align="center" class="float-center" style="width:100%;">
</center>
```

My best regards!

Comment: Thank you a lot. That almost did the job on every client. The only thing is, that when I go to mobile size, the white border is coming around the picture. That means the text and the picture is not vertical aligning. Do you have a guess on what that could be? [link] (http://vouzalis.com/new-test.html) [/link]

Comment: Ah no I was way to quick there. It is actually not rendering more like before on Outlook 2010 and 2013, which were very important for me :-( https://postimg.org/image/mk7y9sr31/

Comment: Outlook will not resize images.

Comment: Okay so the above solution will not work :-/ How the shoot can I make the picture and the text vertical align down then? I have to set a padding on the text, or? Could I give a min-width, or?

Answer (score 1):

Sure!, try this:

Original code:

```
<table class="row">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <th class="small-12 large-12 columns first last" style="padding:0;">
```

Final code:

```
<table class="row">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <th class="small-12 large-12 columns first last" style="padding:0 !important;">
```

Comment: Thank you again for your time. I think the problem is that Outlook is not resizing pictures as @scoopzilla wrote. With the code I have from you now, I still have the white space to the right. https://postimg.org/image/mk7y9sr31/ . I really do not know how I can crack this nut.

Comment: It is working fine in the browser, but not when Outlook render the code. Working fine here: http://vouzalis.com/new-test.html . But yes, I do not know what I can do with the Outlook problem.

Answer (score 1):

### EDIT ** **THIS WILL WORK** **

### **Final version**

Change the < img> to < div> with image background:

```
<th class="small-12 large-12 columns first last" style="padding: 0 !important;">
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th>
          <center>
            <div style="background:blue url('http://www.webdesignmo.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2010/02/6_lion.jpg') no-repeat center; background-size:cover;" alt="image of clever meme that made me chuckle">
              <img src="http://www.webdesignmo.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2010/02/6_lion.jpg" style="display:hidden;">
            </div>
          </center>
        </th>
     </tr>
  </tbody>
```

Comment: In addition, the div fits the image size automatically, by the hidden property of the image

Comment: Hello. Thank you again. I have to start from scratch again. The problem with your code is that some mail clients are not rendering div tags correctly. So the text below will not align with the pictures. In genereal div tags are no go in emails. I thank you for all your time.

Comment: Sorry not to be able to help you... My best regards!! Glad to help!